# How to dynamically set mediaplayer source?

Tags: android, adt

I am wondering what the best way to dynamically set a media-player data source?I have a spinner full of different mp3 files that can be played(around 9 or so currently), I also have a radiogroup that selects the time the sound should be played(4 possible time options).

Is there anyway to make this more efficient rather than having alot of switches in place, 9 songs could possibly be selected(one at a time) and played at 4 different lengths , just seems unwieldy to have all these switch statements.

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){   
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)

            {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                switch(index)
                {
                case 0: //would be 9 of these, represents the song choices
                    final MediaPlayer md = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);
                    int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    switch(id)
                    {
                    case R.id.radio0: // 4 of these for each song, representing play length
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (md.isPlaying()) {
                                    md.pause();
                                    btn.setText("Paused");
                                }
                                else {
                                    md.start();
                                    md.setLooping(true);
                                    btn.setText("Playing");
                                    }
                                }});
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok could you set a variable the amount of time the radio button represents, and then create a postDelayed to stop the mediaPlayer after that amount of time?

```
    int timeTillStop = 15000;

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            mp.stop;
          }
       }, timeTillStop );
```

now you just have to figure which one of the 9 sounds to play?

Comment: Since i have 4 different cases representing the 4 possible different play lengths, and forseeably 9 different audio tracks a user could choose, i would have to have the nine different audio tracks for each Case, using that many `if(index == ???)` seems inefficient?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking how to set up and use mediaPLayer. Give me a second to re-think this.

Comment: I reworded my question to better reflect what im asking.